# Зависла установка monodevelop Mac OS

Tags: c#, mac, mono, monodevelop

Ввожу команды по инструкции с [monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/)

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin:$PATH"
export ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/share/aclocal"
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
cd monodevelop
./configure --profile=mac
make
cd main/build/MacOSX && make MonoDevelop.app && open MonoDevelop.app
```

И на команде `make` он уже больше часа стоит, что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: F#, не C#: "Windows | Prerequisites and Source | ...Install Visual Studio 2017 with the .NET Desktop and .NET Core workloads and the **F#** optional component (note, **F# is disabled by default** so need to enable it in the VS installer)"

Comment: @Alias вы о чем вообще? причем тут VS?

Comment: @tym32167 поторопился. это из раздела по установке для Windows.